# Online text based game design - Am I linking the databases correctly?

Tags: database-design, performance, optimization, normalization, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to recreate an old game that I used to play that went offline quite some time ago. I'm doing this as a hobby project for myself with the hope that maybe a few hundred people might enjoy it once it's finished. It's obviously a long way off as I'm teaching myself as I go but figured I'd start with the database design.

It's a simple (to play) game. You create an empire with a particular race, you create buildings which influence your population, resources, etc and military. The game updates once an hour and depending on what you've built, you start to progress or gain networth. - I hope this is a brief overview to understand the type of game I'm attempting to make? There's no graphical interface, everythings done in text using tables, etc..

Anyways, so I started to use MySQL Workbench to try and map out the databases and now I've realised how much it's going to require in the background. I've got a screenshot of what I've laid out (which I'll post below) and I'd like to know if, in it's current and basic form, it will work. Of course, there's ALOT more to go into this but I want to know that I'm on the right track before progressing.

Thank you for the help.

Here's [the screenshot](https://imgur.com/Tz7tDqd)!

& This is what I'm working with: [Web Archive of "races" guide for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6g1y.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's *correct*, although, as noticed by yourself , it's pretty crude.

This has been asked months ago. Why didn't anyone answer it yet?

Are you still working on this project?

I wonder if you really have the right skills to complete this... If it's indeed interesting, I could help you with the database architecture.

One word of advice: MySQL does not work well with huge amount of relational data.

Regards, Marcus Vinicius.